# JDK timezone issue on Turkey ("Asia/Istanbul" or "Europe/Istanbul")

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, java-7, timezone-offset

Can anyone help with the following problem?

1. My operating system is latest windows 10 and its time zone is `(UTC+0300) Istanbul` (Daylight saving has been removed and time zone was set to `+0300` after the last regulations in Turkey - 7 September 2016)
2. I am using latest JDK which is 1.8.0_131. Tzdata version of this JDK is **tzdata2017a** which includes time zone changes for Turkey.

This is tiny part of my application that I implemented in main method:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TestMain {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String timeZoneStr = "Asia/Istanbul";
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneStr);
        Date localDate = new Date();
        System.out.println(localDate);
        localDate.setTime(155631515L);
        System.out.println(localDate);
        System.out.println(getUTCFromLocal(localDate, timeZone));
   }

    public static Date getUTCFromLocal(Date localDate, TimeZone localTimeZone) {
         return new Date(localDate.getTime()-localTimeZone.getOffset(localDate.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Result of the code is :

> Sun May 21 15:19:48 EET 2017
>
> Fri Jan 02 21:13:51 EET 1970
>
> Fri Jan 02 19:13:51 EET 1970

According to latest time zone update, last line of output should be "Fri Jan 02 **18:13:51** EET 1970", not "Fri Jan 02 19:13:51 EET 1970".

In additon to this, when I create new date object (`new java.util.Date()`), the information in that object seems correct and time zone on `+0300`, but if I use `setTime` method of `Date` object time zone information changes to `+0200`.

When date object created with `new java.util.Date()`:

[image: Screenshot when object created]

When `localDate.setTime(155631515L)` method executed:

[image: Screenshot when setTime(155631515L) method used]

I also reproduced same issue on other JDK versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timezone change in Turkey was in September 2016. So for a date in the year 1970 the old rules apply. At that time, the timezone was +0200, and as you have a date from January, there was no summertime added. If you try a date from July 1970, you should have a difference of 3 hours to UTC.

The change from 2016 although sometimes called 'we use summertime all the year' actually means that Turkey shifted its timezone by one hour and now has the new zone's not-summertime all the year.

If you play around with the dates around September 2016 you will find the point where the calculation changes.

Comment: Actually, the rules have changed *many* times since 1970.  You can review [the entire tzdb entry](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2017a/europe#L3505-L3652), or you can just check out [time in 1970 in Istanbul](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/turkey/istanbul?year=1970).  But you are correct, it was indeed +0200 in January of 1970. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson many thanks for the addition and for the link to the tzdb entry